# Proportion of papers marked by the kind tutor

Tags: probability

Two tutors mark exam papers. The first tutor is kind and gives mark "passed" to a typical student with probability 0.6. The second tutor is angry and his pass rate is only 0.4. After exam papers were marked, it was found out that 54% of the students had passed. What is the proportion of papers marked by the kind tutor? The answer is 0.7.

Comment: Let x be papers marked by the kind tutor, then 1-x - papers marked by the angry tutor. 0.6x +(1-x)*0.4=0.54 and x=0.7

Comment: But is there another way to calculate it?

Answer (score 0):

Let the total number of students be $N$. 
Let $x$ papers go to the kind teacher and obviously, the remaining $(N-x)$ papers go to the angry one.

*Case $1$:* Consider the kind teacher. He gives a "pass" with probability $0.6$. So the total number of students who passed is $0.6x$.

*Case $2$:* Consider the angry teacher. He gives a "pass" with probability $0.4$. So the total number of students who passed is $0.4(N-x)$.

Totally only $54\%$ of students have passed $=0.54N$.

Equating we have $$0.6x+ 0.4(N-x)=0.54N \implies x=0.7N$$ i.e, $70\%$ of papers were marked by the kind teacher.